# How to only print the first value in the row from a CSV file in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, csv, readline, readlines

I have an excel sheet (.csv file) with the `lat`s and `long`s of different traffic camera locations and I have built a Ruby program that uses the `haversine` and `geocoder` gems to find the distance between the address that the user inputs and the different camera locations in the CSV file, then prints out the closest camera to the address that the user provided.

My problem is, it prints out the entire row of information for the closest camera, and I would like it to just print out the first value in the row (the intersection of the location of the nearest traffic camera).

The CSV file is similar to this:

---

**Location                                           Latitude           Longitude     Operational**

St. Charles @ Washington Ave.       29.93102 
         
-90.086 
           
Y

So my question is, to simplify, how do I get it to print out:

```
St. Charles @ Washington Ave. is 1.0351466822038633 miles away!
```

Instead of:

```
St. Charles @ Washington Ave.,30.015934,-90.075197,Y is 1.0351466822038633 miles away!
```

I don't want it to print out the extra values like the `lat`, `long`, and operational status (Y), just the name of camera intersection.

Here is a snippet of the code (without giving out too much of my code, in case other students receive this same assignment in the future and need to figure it out for themselves):

```
require 'csv'
require 'haversine'
require 'geocoder'


# ***missing code that does all of the work converting the distance between the given address 
# and the addresses in the .CSV file and finds the closest traffic camera***

min_num = distance #in miles, calculated by Haversine and Geocoder

# reads the line of the CSV file with the shortest distance to the input address and assigns value to the variable 'closest_cam'

closest_cam = CSV.readlines("./cameras.csv", headers: true)[index_num]

# prints the closest camera to the given address and how far away it is (in miles), 
# the problem is that it prints the entire row, with lats, longs, etc. instead of just the name of the closest camera intersection.. ):<        

puts "#{closest_cam} is #{min_num} miles away!"
```

Answer (score 0):

`puts #{closest_cam[0]} is #{min_num} miles away!`
The closest_cam variable is the row (array) with each column being a position in that array.

From read out of the CSV module (really identical to readlines):
https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.6.1/libdoc/csv/rdoc/CSV.html#method-i-readlines

> Slurps the remaining rows and returns an Array of Arrays.

So all you need to do is call that first column in the row array:
`#{closest_cam[0]}` and you can call the other columns with 1,2,ect.

**EDIT:**
I would be careful though if you have a csv with more rows the real answer would be that `closest_cam` is in fact the whole csv as an array with each row as a position in that array as an array itself.

So the answer would be `closest_cam[0][0]` the first [0] to get the first row in the csv array and the second [0] to get the first column of that first row.

Comment: closest_cam[0][0] just returned the first letter of the name, but closest_cam[0] returned the full name of the first entry in the row. Thank you so much! <3

Comment: @VictoriaGraves Make sure to accept an answer if it solves your problem

Comment: Glad it helped! As Виктор said please accept the answer as it lets the community know you got a correct answer. :)